# Need to slide in header on load

Tags: javascript, header, slider

I am working on a site and would like the header to slide into the page from the top after the rest of the page has loaded. 
Can anyone help with this?
Thanks

site is at choptlogic.com/atmananda
pw 123

Comment: You should look at jQuery and its animate functions. Makes this stuff real easy...

Answer (score 1):

As Chris Moutray suggests in his comment to your question, an ideal solution would be to use jQuery and one of its animations, e.g.,:

```
$(function() {
    // When document is ready show the header using slideDown
    // See http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/
    $("#myHeader").slideDown(1000, function() {
        // Animation complete callback
    });
});​
```

To illustrate, I just made a simple example of how to accomplish such effect using jQuery and the `slideDown` animation - the example is placed at this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WAQLz/

References: http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

Comment: thanks this is very helpful.. although what library should I download and reference in my header script?

Comment: @StephenPilkington you can download the latest from http://jquery.com or you could use a direct reference from a CDN eg http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js

Comment: @StephenPilkington At least, you should put this script at the bottom of your page and remember to include jQuery before you execute the code that does the animation (as it requires jQuery to work).

As this is the accepted answer - would you please mark it as accepted then? :)